# IE7 JSON Response: Object Expected.. Works in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-7, response, object-expected

This is the last thing I have to do before I can send my beloved webapp into the wild, but of course IE7 is being difficult with me!!

I am using the JQuery Form plugin to upload data to my server. A servlet class will then run some operations with the file and shoot back some JSON to the client. As always, Chrome and Firefox handle the response like champs and give me the output I expect.

Internet Explorer 7 does not. I get an "Object Expected" error.... I have narrowed down my problem to a single function. I have made an educated guess that IE7 is not handling the response properly, but I really don't know. Here is the actual code that causes problems:

```
function uploadScript() {

$("#uploadScript").ajaxSubmit({
    beforeSend: function() {

        $("#uploadScript").attr("disabled", true);

    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        if(response != undefined) {
            commandArray = ([]).concat(response.command);
            paramsArray = ([]).concat(response.params);
            IDArray = ([]).concat(response.id);
            commandID = response.commandID;
            updateScriptView();
        }

    }
})

}
```

I have already tried explicitly setting the response header content type to 'application/json' to no avail. I have even read somewhere that such a header will even cause IE to bug out, so that front has certainly been confusing.

Perhaps it is the JSON syntax? Nope! I checked it, double checked it, then ran it through JSONLint just to be sure.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: **The JSON response** literally is this:

```
{ "command" : ["sequential","wait","tune","endsequential"],"params" : [["5"],["00:00:03"],["202","RA29B[*]"],["100000"]],"id" : [100000,100002,100003,100001],"commandID" : 100004}
```

Eye-friendly is this:

```
{
"command": [
    "sequential",
    "wait",
    "tune",
    "endsequential"
],
"params": [
    [
        "5"
    ],
    [
        "00:00:03"
    ],
    [
        "202",
        "RA29B[*]"
    ],
    [
        "100000"
    ]
],
"id": [
    100000,
    100002,
    100003,
    100001
],
"commandID": 100004
}
```

**ANSWERED!** Apparently, my $.attr() call in the beforeSend option of the ajaxSubmit() was causing problems in IE7. I do not know why this is the case, and my Googling yielded no results (Gotta Google the right question to get the right answer). Anyway, removing this code block solved my issue. I appreciate ALL the help that was given to me. Thanks guys!

Comment: Please post the JSON response, even if it passes JSONLint we're talking Internet Explorer here :-)

Comment: Exactly what line causes the problem?  You may be able to tell by using IE8 or IE9 in IE7 compat mode, and check with the developer tools.

Comment: @ZeroPage Okay, the question has been updated!

Comment: @Pointy IE7 tells me it is line 27, but this is unhelpful because many of my scripts are linked externally and the error dialog does not specify where this line 27 actually is

Comment: ¿So this code is in an external file? How are you including them? (could you show that too?)

Comment: Right - that's why I'd suggest trying it in IE8 or IE9, because the developer tools are at least somewhat useful.  (It's not 100% guaranteed that you'll be able to reproduce the problem, but there's a pretty good chance.)

Comment: if you are absolutely desperate you could put an alert('n'); between each line in the success callback?

Comment: @Alfabravo My word choice may have been misleading there, I'm not sure. Anyway, I'm linking the JS in the html of the page like this: 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
 src="resources/editscript.js"></script>

Comment: @Pointy I can't install IE8 because I don't have admin privileges XD

Comment: @ZeroPage Alert statements have shown me that execution does not get into the success function

Comment: @dr7164 well how are you going to test your site in IE8 and IE9?

Comment: @Pointy I'd be glad to discuss my poor practices in private, and keeping in that spirit will allow us to stay on topic here. As I am fairly new to **web** development, I will welcome your tips/suggestions/criticisms with open arms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using malsup plugin. If that's the case then the git repo has some known issues with this plugin:

https://github.com/malsup/form/issues

Check that your issue is not one already reported. Also check you jQuery version

this is the one for you: https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/179

Comment: Thanks, at first glance it seems this might be able to help. I see that the OP solved the problem and posted some sort of the solution as an edit. I don't think I fully understand what he did to solve it though. Can someone explain what he did? I am sorry to be an inconvenience about this, but I'd love to make sense of how he fixed it!


**edit: his solution is:** 

I solve my problem by new handler for form with upload and include files into this file and I see differents between .ajax and jquery.form - first transfer all &quot;included&quot; files to reloaded page, second - not!</p>

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that the Form plugin could be the cause of the error. The code block that I was trying to execute in the beforeSend component of the ajax options was causing the errors. Removing the $.attr() call from the beforeSend option fixed my problem. I will give you the answer credit as your answer canvassed my findings.